# count index in a list to x number python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list with like this that goes from 0 to 1000 .

`x = ['0_1','0_2','0_3' ..., '1000_1','1000_2','1000_3']`

I need it to count every time the char in index changes like I show below.

`list_leng = len(x)`

`for i in range(0, list_leng):
    y = x[i]
    z = y[0]
    print this should iterate through all the list and only print when the z number changes ' # how should I make it print '`

Comment: Where do you declare `y`?

Comment: Inside the loop as index for "x" so it can be used to get the char 0 from that Word index the main point is to compare its number, seems like I forgot to say it, I am sorry, it should compare the `int(z)` so it prints its number, I am using a function the get characters that are multiples of "x" numer so I need it to print only the multiples but still has to read one by one so it completes a loop for creating files in subfolders calling an external program, so basically is (do this action every "x" times then change folder)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question well, the answer must be something like this;

```
comparisonText = ""
for each in x:
    preNumber = each.split('_')[0]
    if comparisonText != preNumber:
        print preNumber, 'is different than previous.'
        comparisonText = preNumber #change the comparisonText
```